# HTML object tag not displaying web page

Tags: html, http

For some reason the following recently quit working:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Form 4</h2>
    <object data="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1463959/000155335015000539/xslF345X03/khesin4.xml" type="text/html">
      Could not retrieve form.
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is meant to display an SEC filing, but recently quit working.  The bare url works fine.  Is this something in the code or the way the SEC server is working.

Puzzled.

Comment: I get `Refused to display 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1463959/000155335015000539/xslF345X03/khesin4.xml' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` in the console. Which means that the page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

Comment: did you try iframe instead of object?

Comment: Tried iframe, same result.  Looks like the X-Frame-Options issue is the real problem.  I don't suppose there's a way around that, eh?

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve a workaround by first downloading this file (php/CURL seems to be a good choice for simulating browser behavior), making a local copy, then using it. Check for file update on each call to avoid user having old version, or with the good regularity to avoid being banned from the sec.gov server.

Comment: Thanks.  I will explore this approach.